# Why is a full Matlab array (X) returning a false in 'if X'?

Tags: excel, matlab

I have some Matlab code that checks if an array is non zero before operating and it's being skipped even though the array is 3 by 1000+.

The code is just: if X

The array is read from an excel file using 'xlsread' and only gives the error for a particular data file but works for any other input data file I use.

Any idea why this is?

Answer (score 3):

It only takes one element of an array to be zero-valued for this test to fail

```
>> A = rand(100, 3) + 1;
>> if A; disp('True'); else disp('False'); end
True     

>> A(35) = 0;
>> if A; disp('True'); else disp('False'); end
False
```

If you're looking to check that the array doesn't contain only zeros, you can use the `any` keyword:

```
>> A = rand(100, 3) + 1;
>> A(35) = 0;
>> if any(A(:)); disp('True'); else disp('False'); end
True

>> A = 0 * A;
>> if any(A(:)); disp('True'); else disp('False'); end
False
```

**Edit:**

Apologies, as SCFrench mentions in the comments, use `any(A(:))` to test each element in an array rather than `any(A)` — this has been duly edited in my answer above.

Comment: Use any(A(:)) to avoid the problem that b3 mentions in his answer.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. I'm surprised it took so long for that bug to pop up.

Answer (score 0):

The [any](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/any.html) function doesn't quite work for this problem as it treats the columns of a matrix as vectors:

```
>> any([0 0 1; 0 0 1; 0 0 1])
ans =
     0     0     1
```

Instead, use the [nnz](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/nnz.html) function to count the number of non-zero elements in a matrix:

```
>> nnz([0 0 1; 0 0 1; 0 0 1])
ans =
     3
>> nnz([0 0 0; 0 0 0; 0 0 0])
ans =
     0
```